# Write docker logs to file even after container restarts

Tags: docker, logging

I can continuously write logs of a docker container to a log file with the command:

```
docker logs -f container &> log_file
```

But one problem is when the container crashes and then restarts, the log file will no longer be appended to.

How can I achieve that the logs after the container restarts will be appended to the log file?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```bash
while true; do
  docker logs --tail -f container 2>&1 | tee -a <LOG_FILE_NAME>
done
```

Where `-a` is the **append** option.

Comment: How can this handle container restarts?

Comment: You are right, I updated it. ;)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but can you tell me where this code snippet should go? Should I put this in a script? And if so, how can I run it? @AntonioPetricca

Comment: Also, will there be any duplicate lines after a container restart? @AntonioPetricca